# How to include two calls of >> in one setw?

Tags: c++, io, iomanip

Take this a minimal working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    cout    << setw(10) << "aaaaaaa"
            << setw(10) << "bbbb"
            << setw(10) << "ccc"
            << setw(10) << "ddd"
            << setw(10) << endl; 

    for(int i(0); i < 5; ++i){

        char ch = ' ';
        if ( i == 0 )
            ch = '%';
        cout << setw(10) << i
             << setw(10) << i << ch
             << setw(10) << i
             << setw(10) << i
             << setw(10) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
   aaaaaaa      bbbb       ccc       ddd
         0         0%         0         0
         1         1          1         1
         2         2          2         2
         3         3          3         3
         4         4          4         4
```

What I would like to do is to include `<< i << ch` in one field of `setw(10)` so that columns are aligned properly.

Comment: Did you read documentation of [setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, so the only solution in here is to concatenate into one string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably combine `i` and `ch` in one string, `setw` wouldn't accept this behavior natively

try this snippet

```
 cout << setw(10) << i
      << setw(10) << std::to_string(i) + ch;
```

Comment: I would like to avoid this approach if necessary.

Comment: @CroCo What was your motive for avoiding this behavior?

Comment: @CroCo So you want to avoid this approach, but accept it over others. Why?

Comment: @Yunnosch as I said if necessary. I've already solved the problem by performing concatenation. What I was looking for is a shortcut something like passing a flag but it seems the language doesn't support this functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Since we are looking at either `' '` or `'%'` you can simply calculate statically.

```
cout << setw(10) << i
     << setw( 9) << i << ch
     << setw(10) << i
     << setw(10) << i
     << setw(10) << endl;
```

Comment: Very simple, very elegant.

Answer (score 3):

You need to concatenate them into one string, like this:

```
#include <string>
cout << setw(10) << std::to_string(i) + ch;
```

in general.

But if you know that `i` is one character you could use:

```
cout << setw(9) << i << ch;
```

which might the case for you, since `i` seems to be `' '` or `'%'`.

Comment: Is this the only solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure to understand your need.

You could use some [std::ostringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) like e.g.

```
 std::ostringstream os;
 os << i << ch << std::flush;
 std::cout << setw(10) << os.str();
```

You could build a string, like [James Maa answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273085/841108)